# TextMate find text and then delete entire line?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

I'll show you what I want to do using a textmate command or bundle:

Lets say we have the following document:

```
foo  
diddy
  bah
foo
foobah
diddy
```

I want to find and delete all the lines matching `bah`, the desired ouput in this case would be:

```
foo
diddy
foo
diddy
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the document you want to filter open,

- Cmd-F to bring up the **Finder
  window**
- Next, below the two text-entry boxes,
  click *Regular Expression*
- In the ***Find*** text box, type in
  this regexp (without the spaces):

  **^ . * ? bah . * ? $**
- In the *Replace* text box, do not type
  in anything--make sure it blank,
  i.e., no whitespace characters
- With the cursor at the beginning of
  the document you want to filter,
  click one of the buttons at the
  bottom of the Find Window--e.g.,
  *Replace All* to remove all of the matching lines in one step, or
  *Replace and Find* to step through the lines one at a time

That's it.

---

Here's a more automated way to do the same thing:

- from the Menu Bar, select *Filter
  Through Command* from the *Text*
  pull-down menu
- enter this into the text box at the
  top of the small window that appears:

  **sed ' / ^ . * bah . * $ / d '**
- select Document as Input and select
  Replace Document as Output
- Click Execute

[*Note: i inserted spaces between the regexp tokens in both examples because for some reason the asterisks '*' were not rendering in HTML page]

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! everything is working almost right, maybe I'm missing something, but after following your instructions the output I'm getting is this: http://gist.github.com/500613 instead of http://gist.github.com/500616.

Comment: i coudldn't reproduce your output; anyway, i edited my Answer above to include an alternative using "Filter Through Command" (and which is actually easier to use).

Answer (score 3):

Building on top of @doug's answer
Since the user wants to delete the line after the match, the solution using Regex is

```
^ . * ? bah . * ? $\n
```

Matching the \n at the end will remove the line